# Expand div horizontally not vertically

Tags: css, html

I have a div with

```
display:inline-block;
postion:relative;
```

inside a div with

```
display:block;
width:348px;
overflow:hidden;
```

When the contents of the inner div overflow, I want them to expand `horizontally`, not `vertically`. The contents of the inner div consists of thumbnails of photos

Answer (score 17):

You just need to set `white-space: nowrap` on either of the divs (the property is inherited). [(Source)](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

***Sidenote***: The inner div is not necessary for this to work.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKUaa/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <!-- Thumbnails -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 348px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.container div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ray Z!

Overflow does matters. So in order to write your css as just

```
overflow:"hidden"
```

you should use

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the width and overflow-x as auto for the inner div

```
    <div id = "outer">
     <div id = "inner"></div>
    </div>

#outer{
width: 400px;
height: 300px;
border: red thin dotted;
}

#inner{
margin: 15px;
height: 280px;
width: auto;
border: green thin solid;
overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jgrgb/